# Create a simple function for combobox dialog in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have a Python3 program with tkinter and in some part of code I want to "ask" from a list of options. I see that neither simplebox or messagebox has this options, only for text.. How can I do it to call like `result = simplechoicebox("title","Text",["Choices"],parent)` and return result?

I tried to do it by functions of tkinter, but I didn't find it..

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Menu, messagebox,simpledialog,ttk

def c_funcbutton():
    res = simpledialog.askstring('Ask','Title',parent=main_window)
    return res #Or do anything..


main_window = Tk()
main_window.title("My Window")

menu = Menu(main_window)
menu_com = Menu(menu)
menu_com = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu_com.add_command(label='Here',command=c_funcbutton)
menu_com.add_command(label='Another')
menu.add_cascade(label='Equipos', menu=menu_com)

main_window.config(menu=menu)

main_window.mainloop()
```

I expect to be able to ask of a Choicebox/Combobox in `c_funcbutton()` and return it

Comment: I don't think there is a readily made widget for this, but you can simply use `Toplevel` combined with `combobox` and `button` widgets to achieve what you want.

Comment: You can have an example..? I can do a "Window" but I don't know how to do as dialog for returning data...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something like `result = simplechoicebox("title","Text",["Choices"],parent)`, you can just make your own class for it.

```
class SimpleChoiceBox:
    def __init__(self,title,text,choices):
        self.t = Toplevel()
        self.t.title(title if title else "")
        self.selection = None
        Label(self.t, text=text if text else "").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.c = ttk.Combobox(self.t, value=choices if choices else [], state="readonly")
        self.c.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.c.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.combobox_select)

    def combobox_select(self,event):
        self.selection = self.c.get()
        self.t.destroy()
```

Now you can define your `c_funcbutton` as below:

```
def c_funcbutton():
    global res
    res = SimpleChoiceBox("Ask","What is your favourite fruit?",["Apple","Orange","Watermelon"])
```

It won't return the value however - a normal class works differently than a `simpledialog`. But you can access the choice directly by `res.selection` as below:

```
menu_com.add_command(label='Another',command=lambda: print (res.selection))
```